# Creating new sockets with no bandwidth left

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, nio

I'm looking for an answer to a hypothetical, but not implausible, problem that I may run into, and possible ways to solve the problem. My question is: **what happens when you attempt to connect a new TCP socket when there's no bandwidth left to do the handshake in a reasonable amount of time?**

Does the socket just time out? How realistic is this scenario? I'm building an application that is responsible for querying over 50,000 (Minecraft multiplayer) servers as quickly and accurately as possible - hopefully within minutes. This includes performing DNS address and SRV queries. These servers receive an "uptime penalty" on our website if we cannot connect to them so it is important that we know whether or not they are actually available.

I have the underlying networking handled using an extremely lightweight `java.nio.channels` reactor implementation, but now I'm worried that the application will be extremely I/O bound. **How do you guys recommend solving this tradeoff between bandwidth and accuracy?**

Comment: A TCP handshake times out after about a minute, which is orders of magnitude longer than it really takes. TCP has congestion control so that there always is bandwidth available for anther connection. Your concerns seem misplaced.

Comment: I'm trying to solve C10k times 5 on a small VPS here... should it really be that easy? What about socket read/write timeouts when there's 50k handshakes going on simultaneously?

Comment: Add more details about the queries you are performing, possibly with examples.

Comment: I run a Minecraft server list and I need to query the servers to get information and show it on my website. Here's the protocol documentation: http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping